# setting up qt creator 2.7 on windows

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am beginning to learn Qt gui programming and for this I downloaded Qt Creator 2.7.1 for win xp.
I installed it but when i try to create a new project it asks me to select a kit. There are no kits installed so they say me to setup one. I installed the MinGW compiler (and selected the mingw-g++.exe but i thinks its not right). But when I set up the Qt version they ask me to locate the qmake.exe which i cant find anywhere on my system.

please guide me on setting up the creator so that i have a painless experience in the future. Please tell me the correct steps and the right files to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator is not enough to create applications using Qt framework. You also need Qt framework (the Qt libraries) installed, see the download page [here](https://qt-project.org/downloads) and depending on the version of Qt you want you can download one of these:
   *Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 650 MB)* - this one is kind of an SDK and include a MinGW, Creator and obviously the Qt framework, but if you added your MinGW to system's path you will have to remove it from there, because if you have multiple versions in path you will get some errors when you build applications
or
   *Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB)* - for this i think you need to install MinGW your self - but i'm not sure about that